# Interrupt mapping in Arduino Due

Tags: arduino

I got some problem while working with arduino due.From what i know each timer channel has 3 compare registers,2 i/o lines (for A and B compares) and one Interrupt number.
Now is there a way to raise specific interrupt for A,B,C compares belonging to same channel?

I am confused as there is only one interrupt number attached to one channel while three events are happening(A compare ,B compare ,C compare) per channel.

Is there a way to select a particular procedure to be executed for a particular compare event.
(i.e. selection of a particular procedure under one interrupt number)

Note: I am working in 'Waveform Mode'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [the following post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=gos91tdepbv5vadr7be2gnblg1&topic=130423.msg1007641#msg1007641) where cmaglie details that each of the 9 possible interrupts (3 channels in each of the 3 timer counters) can generate a unique interrupt, independent of the others.

In the post there is a nice explanation and example of setting up the resources. Along with a table that details which parameter correspond to appropriate settings.